# Is there any way to connect directly to a SharePoint database?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

A list inside our Intranet SharePoint has reached the 5000 items limit threshold. We followed the Microsoft recommendation on how to overcome this limit adding indexed columns combined with filters as described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59). Now, the issue is solved and I'm wondering if there's any way to download all the items from the list without filters. Datasheet view allows to download all the data without filters but I'm not sure if this datasheet view is going to collapse some day. Does anyone know how to connect directly to the entire's list data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to do anything with the database, check out the [daily time window](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59#__bkmktimewindow), which is a setting that allows you to configure a time of day where list thresholds are ignored. No, don't set this for 24 hours a day, as the list threshold is an important aspect for keeping the farm healthy.

Comment: Thanks, but... What if we need to have the whole data available 24x7?

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood the requirements? With indexes and views, users should have access to browse through all items. But you need to actually download all the current files at any time of day? What, specifically, do you mean by download? But other options include using excel/powerpivot to connect to the list, or SSRS to create a report. You can also go the coding route and access the data via REST or CSOM.

Comment: There's an excel report which needs to be fed by all the items on a list. Actually, I'm downloading all the items available through Datasheet View, and exporting it to a different Excel file. My default view (All Items) does not allow me to download all the items because is filtered to avoid limit threshold. Would you be so kind to guide me on how to access the data via REST or CSOM?

Comment: Let's try an easier way first. If you have excel 2016, try the following from excel: data tab --> get data--> from other sources --> sharepoint list.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Office version is 2013. But, I've seen that I can download PowerQuery for Office 2013 and install it to connect to the SharePoint list. Is this Power Query add-in licensed? I was able to accomplish what I was looking for with this add-in. Thanks @Mike2500

Comment: No additional licensing to use it! Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you see the list with Auditor or Admin account, the default threshold limit is 20,000 you can download the data or export to excel.

[image: Default threshold limit]